# How do I register for Soundcloud API. Currently receiving Error

Tags: api, registration, soundcloud

I am receiving the following error when attempting to register for Soundcloud API.  Can you please advise me how to resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As they say, they're not allowing new registrations for api at this time, and this is for some time now (i remember trying to register but got the same message).
Maybe people were abusing the api so they need to think of more efficient way..

Comment: I am hoping for a response from Soundcloud Dev to see the status.  Or maybe a work around if anyone has come up with one.  Thank you.